# mxgraph block mxevent effect

Tags: mxgraph

I'm trying to add a simple 'confirm to remove dialog' on my `mxgraph` based app, but can't keep the remove event from actually happening when I want to cancel it. So far, I'm listening to `mxEvent.REMOVE_CELLS`, in my simplest approach I tried something like:

```
graph.addListener(mxEvent.REMOVE_CELLS, (sender, evt) => {
    evt.consume();
});
```

As far as I know, `consume` should keep the event from propagating, and as I understood to have effect at all, but the nodes are deleted no matter what. I even tried to `undo` immediatelly after the event, and still not working.

**Is there even a straight forward way to keep an event from happening and apply a different logic instead**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I ended up overriding `mxGraph.removeCells` to fire my own custom event, looks something like:

```
mxGraph.prototype.removeCells = function(cells, includeEdges) {
  ...

  if (shouldntRemoveDirectly) {
    this.fireEvent(new mxEventObject('beforeRemoveLoop', 'cells', cells, 'includeEdges', includeEdges));
    return;
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Hello ssantos, Are you working on mxGraph. Mind helping me answer my problem please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69578540/how-can-the-cell-listen-to-the-moving-or-resizing-event-in-mxgraph